# mariaDB sum function Get decimal result

Tags: mariadb

```
$result=mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT sum(cost)as ucost FROM uout WHERE id='aaaa'");
$out=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo $out[ucost];
```

**Output**
    1.000000001328541e18 // result value

I want to get the decimal result.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast it into a [`DECIMAL`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/decimal/):

```
SELECT CAST(sum(cost) AS DECIMAL(32,4)) as ucost FROM uout WHERE id='aaaa'
```

Comment: There was one enormous value in the COST.
I applied the code you gave me.
thanks.

Comment: In case you have really big values, you can use `DECIMAL(65,4)` to get the maximum integer size.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` for monetary values.

Check the values -- 1...e18 is a ridiculously large value.

```
SELECT * FROM uout WHERE id = 'aaaa' AND cost >= 1e16;
```

You may find a surprise value.

Comment: I have already seen one by one in phpmyadmin.
I should have thought of your method more quickly.